# Slow DataGridView drawing using a List<> as DataSource in C#

Tags: c#, list, performance, datagridview, datasource

I have been reading about Data Grid View slow drawing issues here, but I can't find a solution, so I will try to share a clear sample of my code, and a time measurement (More than 6 seconds...).

I'm using DoubleBuffer and VirtualMode on a i7 CPU, 16Gb RAM, 2Gb GPU and the drawing time is the same. I have a List<> (About 10.000 elements of simple structs) and I'm using it as DataSource for a DataGridView, here the code:

```
this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;

this.dataGridViewList = this.completeList.FindAll (
    r => r.code >= 0
);

this.myDataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
this.myDataGridView.DataSource = this.dataGridViewList;
this.myDataGridView.ClearSelection();

this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
```

And here is the time, it is really really slow, the List<> is not the problem, it can be sort in miliseconds, I'm sure the problem is the DataGridView refill or drawing.

[image: My error]

Comment: _I'm using DoubleBuffer_ On the DataGridView or on the Form? There is also dgv.Suspend/ResumeLayout. You may also want to turn off any columnwidth automatism until the data are all there!

Comment: Your image shows a timespan of `<=6.097` milliseconds which is pretty fast. A millisecond is a thousandth of a second.

Comment: Sorry, I'm Spanish, here the point '.' is your comma ',' as thousands separator :P

Comment: I am guessing you are looking in the wrong place for this “lag” in performance. In my test using a simple `List<T>`, with one “million” elements, consistently, took less than 0.4 seconds to load into the grid. It took around 1.5 seconds to “load” one million records into the `List<T>`. This is “without” double buffering or virtual mode. 10,000 elements are NOT a lot of records and a default `DataGridView` should handle that many records quickly out of the box.

Comment: Point being, unless you are doing something “after” you run the posted code… I would look at how you are getting your data. I suggest putting a `Stopwatch` around “loading the data into the `List<T>`” and another `Stopwatch` around the code setting the grids `DataSource`. This should show you “where” this lag is coming from. I am confident it is not coming from `this.myDataGridView.DataSource = this.dataGridViewList;`.

Comment: @JohnG Thanks dude, but you can see how my break points are marked in red on the image, ClearSelection just avoid first row to be selected, so I'm sure the instruction that is taking 6 seconds to end is just this.myDataGridView.DataSource = this.dataGridViewList; My program has a lot of List<> feeding a DataGridView, and it is always the same when elements are about 10.000

Comment: You should make a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I used the “same” code you have posted and I do NOT get the lag you describe using 1 million elements. In addition, the breakpoint (time) you reference would be the `ClearSelection` line if you are “stepping” through the code. Without some code that reproduces the problem, speculation is all you may get.

Comment: What do you mean by… _My program has a lot of List<> feeding a DataGridView_ …? A grid can only display one (1) list at a time. I suggest you give an example of the list the causes the lag. What is in the list? How many fields? It should be obvious that you need to show what this list contains. We know there are 10,000 elements, but what does each element look like?

Comment: Lastly, as I suggested, to truly make sure you are correct that the line `this.myDataGridView.DataSource = this.dataGridViewList;` is where the lag is… then wrap a `Stopwatch` around that line of code and display a message box after that line to show the elapsed time. Example: `Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch(); sw.Start(); this.myDataGridView.DataSource = this.dataGridViewList; sw.Stop(); MessageBox.Show(“Elapsed Time: “ + sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;` This way you do not have to “step” through the code and you should be able to see how long “any” line of code takes to execute.

Comment: Hi @JohnG, thanks for all, I will use Stopwatch a lot. And I have found the problem! My project is very simple, each DataGridView is populated by a different List<>, with simple fields (About 5-10 int and string variables). The very very slow drawn was only when my form Design uses a DataGridView dragged directly from Toolbox/All Windows Forms, otherwhise, if I use other custom components of the solution that looks like a DataGridView they draw as fast as you say! The project I'm working is more than 5 years old, I have just started with it and some of the code is pure bullshit :S